# An upper bound for an integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

I saw many references using the following estimate but I couldn't prove it.

Given $T>0$ and $0 < b \leq \frac{1}{2}$, exist $C(b)$ constant that depends only on $b$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\sqrt{1+s^2}<\frac{1}{T}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}^{2b}}ds \leq C(b) T^{2b-1}.
\end{equation}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By the way, for future reference, you should include your own attempts at solving your problem(s). It is generally the accepted thing to do on this site, and typically gets you much better quality engagement. As it currently stands, your question may be closed because it does not fit the site's standards. See this article for more on this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: For the record, I find this to be an interesting computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an elementary solution: When $T>1$ the domain of integration is empty, so the integral is zero i.e the inequality is trivial. Hence, suppose that $0<T\leqslant 1$. Since $\sqrt{1+s^2}\geqslant \vert s \vert$, we have that $\{\sqrt{1+s^2}<T^{-1}\} \subset (-T^{-1},T^{-1})$. Hence, \begin{align*}
\int_{\sqrt{1+s^2}<T^{-1}} \frac 1{(1+s^2)^b} \, ds &\leqslant \int_{-T^{-1}}^{T^{-1}}\frac 1{(1+s^2)^b} \, ds \\
&= 2  \int_0^1\frac 1{(1+s^2)^b} \, ds + 2 \int_1^{T^{-1}}\frac 1{(1+s^2)^b} \, ds.
\end{align*} Using that $(1+s^2)^{-b} \leqslant 1$ in the first integral and that $(1+s^2)^{-b}\leqslant s^{-2b}$ in the second, we obtain \begin{align*}
\int_{\sqrt{1+s^2}<T^{-1}} \frac 1{(1+s^2)^b} \, ds &\leqslant 2 + 2 \int_1^{T^{-1}}\frac {ds}{s^{2b}}  \\
&= 2 + \frac 2{1-2b} \big ( T^{2b-1}-1 \big ) \\
&\leqslant \bigg ( 2 + \frac 2{1-2b} \bigg ) T^{2b-1}
\end{align*} provided that $0<b < \frac12$. For the last inequality, I used that $T^{2b-1}\geqslant 1$. When $b=\frac12$, you instead get that \begin{align*}
\int_{\sqrt{1+s^2}<T^{-1}} \frac 1{(1+s^2)^b} \, ds &\leqslant 2 +2\log(T^{-1}) =2\big(1 +\vert \log(T)\vert\big).
\end{align*} Though  haven't proven it here, you can check that when $b=1/2$ the integral behaves like $\vert \log T \vert$ asymptotically as $T\to 0^+$ which means the your inequality is false in this case and the above inequality is the best you can do.

Comment: Nice. When b is 1/2, we can use a similar idea to bound the integrand from below by $|x|$, so the value of the integral $I$ is at least $|\log T|$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If $T \ge 1$, there is nothing to show, so suppose $T$ is a dyadic number $< 1$, and consider the level sets $E_\lambda = \{s:\sqrt{1+s^2}\sim \lambda\}$. Let $I$ be the value of the integral, so we have
\begin{align*}
I \sim \sum_{\substack{\lambda\ \text{dyadic}\\1< \lambda < T^{-1}}}\lambda^{-2b}|E_\lambda|.
\end{align*}
It's straightforward to check that for $\lambda > 1$, $E_\lambda$ contains and is contained in the union of two intervals of length $\sim\lambda$, hence $|E_\lambda|\sim \lambda$, so overall $I\sim \sum_{1<\lambda < T^{-1}\ \text{dyadic}}\lambda^{-2b+1}$. This sum is a geometric series, so as long as $b<\frac12$, it's majorized by the contribution from the largest value of $\lambda$, namely $\lambda\sim T^{-1}$, so we conclude
$$
I \sim_b T^{2b-1}.
$$
If $b = 1/2$, this approach shows $I\sim \log(1/T)$. The assumption that $T$ be dyadic is superficial since we are looking for an estimate within a constant factor of the true size.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I couldn't understand two steps. The first one is when you mojorized the series by the contribution of the largest value. How did you do this? And the second, is it sufficient to do just for T being a dyadic number?

Comment: Sure thing. The condition on b tells us $-2b+1$ is at least 0, so the sum in lambda is a geometric series with exponent $-2b+1\ge0$. If the exponent is positive then such a series is within a constant (depending on $b$ of its largest summand.

Comment: The assumption that T is dyadic  is inessential because any T is within a multiple of 2 of some dyadic number.

Comment: Thank you very much!!